# Problem syncing Creative Zen Vision M in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mp3-player

I have a Creative Zen Vision M mp3 player. I used to use gnomad2 to add music to it, but I just tried it for the first time since installing Ubuntu 9.10 and it doesn't seem to work.

When I plug in the device, Ubuntu recognises it as a media device, under `gphoto2://[usb:001,009]/`.

When I try to open the Music folder on the device, I get the message:

> Sorry, could not display all the contents of "Music": Failed to get file list: -8: Fixed limit exceeded

Opening Gnomad2 gives the message:

> No jukeboxes found on USB bus.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a solution from the Ubuntu forums: unmount the device then start Gnomad, and it then recognises it!